# Java Selenium WebDriver - How to set ScrollBehavior (elementScrollBehavior) without using Remote WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

on my website I'm trying to automate, there is a floating header. As selenium is always scrolling to the top of an element, I'm getting the error message that some other element would receive the click. After searching a bit on the net, there should be a solution to set the scroll behavior (elementScrollBehavior) as a desired capability.

Now my question: As Desired Capabilities is for remote WebDriver implementation, it's not really useful in my case. Is there a possibility to change the scroll behavior in a way, that I can run my local instance with the behavior of scolling to buttom of an element?

Many Thanks & Regards!

Comment: dc.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 0); // 0- from Top, 1 - from bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desired capabilities are not only for `RemoteWebDriver` implementation, you can set it even on your local driver instances.
For example, if you are using `FirefoxDriver` you could do something like this in your case:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);
```

You can also use `RemoteWebDriver` on your local machine (just pass localhost url), your localhost can also be selenium node, it doesn't have to be on some remote machine.